# WinDbg: Unable to run !address -summary command on crash dump (mini dump with full memory)

Tags: c++, debugging, windbg

I have a crash dump with heap of a native cpp app which I'm trying to debug using WinDbg but when i try to run `!address -summary` command  it keeps running (for hours) without any output while showing following error codes-

```
Failed to retrieve DeallocationStack value for thread xxx (error 80004002)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: How has your dump been generated?

Comment: Can you post the exact dump flags from `.dumpdebug`, please?

Comment: @Dominique It's generated on a crash using a registry setting.  "DumpCount"=dword:00000010
"DumpType"=dword:00000002

Comment: @ThomasWeller User Mini Dump File with Full Memory: Only application data is available

Comment: The WER LocalDumps stuff should work. Maybe just an unlucky capture. Can you get another one?